# Does this four variable quadratic condition describe a convex condition?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is following four variable parametrized quadratic condition $$f(a,b,c,d)=\big((c+d)r-{(a+b)}\big)^2+(r-ab)<\gamma$$ along with conditions $$0<c,d<1<a,b<r$$ convex at any fixed $r,\gamma>1$?

Comment: Have you considered the hessian of $f$?

Comment: It has an eigenvalue of -1, so $f$ is not convex. That is an indication that the feasible set may not be convex.

Comment: @LinAlg How did you get the $-1$? Why only 'may not'?

Comment: numerically. May not because indefinite function can still define convex sets (think $x^3 \leq 0$). I suggest you randomly try points $a,b,c,d$ to find a counterexample using the definition of convexity.

Comment: @LinAlg just for example which region is $x^3\leq0$ convex? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%3C%3D0?